# Which cert files does Git for Windows use

Tags: windows, git, ssl, trust

In the default git install it has a lot of certificates.

I'm still failing to setup SSL in GIT and I'm finding it difficult to work out what git is attempting to do to work with it's use of ssl.

Does anyone knows what all these different cert files are individually for?
Hopefully that will explain why one file will not suffice?

```
C:\opt\git>find . -name "*.crt"
./etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
./etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/CAcert.org_class3.crt
./etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/CAcert.org_root.crt
./mingw64/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
./mingw64/share/pki/ca-trust-legacy/ca-bundle.legacy.default.crt
./mingw64/share/pki/ca-trust-legacy/ca-bundle.legacy.disable.crt
./mingw64/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ca-bundle.trust.crt
./mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
./mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt
./usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ca-bundle.legacy.disable.crt
./usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ca-bundle.legacy.enable.crt
./usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ca-bundle.neutral-trust.crt
./usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ca-bundle.trust.crt
./usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
./usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

Each file contains a great many certs I'm expected to trust with no names. I only really want to trust github and the company I work for. I'm looking to see which of these files I need to edit to make my git installation safe.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question and probably the answer was found.  However, this git command should tell you which crt file is being used; look for http.sslcainfo

git config --list --show-origin